# Where does 13 come from?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, computer-science, recursive-algorithms, dynamic-programming

I am going over the [Rod Cutting Problem](http://users.csc.calpoly.edu/~dekhtyar/349-Spring2010/lectures/lec09.349.pdf)

Everything makes sense to me until

For example, $L$ = {9} has the total cost Cost($L$) = $P$[9] = 13, 
whereas $L$' = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1} has the total cost Cost(L') = 9*P[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBdGQ.png)] = 9 $\lt$ 13

Earlier the author states "Selling a rod of length $i$ units earns $P$[i] dollars." Here is the table $P$ for this problem

[image]

Shouldn't the first cost be 22, if you look at the table? (P[9] = 22) Does anyone know where the 13 is coming from?

One thought I had was that the 13 is the dollars earned minus the length, 22 - 9 which doesn't make sense in the situation either. But this wouldn't work because in the second example, the author doesn't subtract the dollars earned, 9, by the length, 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a typo to me!

There's another typo in the definition of the problem. I think it should read $$\text{Cost}(L) = \sum_{j = 1}^k P[l_j] = \dots$$ instead of $$\text{Cost}(L) - \sum_{j = 1}^k P[l_j] = \dots$$

Comment: ... and another typo in the Example on page 2. $P[i]/i$ should be $\frac{8}{3} = 2\frac{2}{3}$ for $i = 3$, not $2\frac{1}{3}$. This explains why the author claims that $P[i]/i$ is maximized by $i = 3$.

Comment: Yeah thanks for confirming!